# How to create foreign key with ON DELETE CASCADE constraint that references the same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried to create foreign key with ON DELETE CASCADE constraint that references the same table, but that deemed to be impossible due to the following error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Employees_Employees' on table
> 'Employees' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.

How should I be defining my table? My requirements are:

- Employee might not have a manager
- When employee who is a manager is deleted all of his employees are also deleted

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employees]
(
    [EmployeeId] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    [ManagerId] INT NULL,
    --...
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Employees] PRIMARY KEY ([EmployeeId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Employees_Employees] FOREIGN KEY ([ManagerId])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[Employees] ([EmployeeId]) -- ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Comment: You'll need to handle this outside of `CASCADE`. As the error suggests, this could cause cycles, which is an issue. For example, if Employee `1` was the manager of Employee `2`, which was manager of Employee `3`, who was the manager of Employee `1`, you'd have a cycle.

Comment: ^ and my recommendation has always been to just stay away from the cascade features in _any_ scenario. They rarely do anything useful and are much more likely to cause pain. You can handle any type of cascade logic by forcing deletes etc. through stored procedures or, if you can't do that, properly-written triggers.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks, this makes sense.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have similar opinion about triggers hence tried to solve this with cascade. Will read up about forcing deletes. Thank you

Comment: @Larnu, at least Oracle, DB2 and Postgresql handle this cycle without problems. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=3c493b8760eaca79588ba898809f24fe

Comment: Yeah, I'm honestly on the side on Bertrand on this one though, @jarlh ; don't rely on `CASCADE` and instead handle it in the procedure or trigger(s)..

Comment: Triggers are like anything else, if you write crappy triggers, they won't work well. But they give you a lot more control over behavior than the built-in cascade shorthand.

Comment: A ON DELETE CASCADE fk is pretty much a kind of trigger. And both those foreign keys and triggers can cause a lot of problems - if not properly used.

Comment: @jarlh my point is, you can fix a bad trigger, you can't change bad cascade behavior. And you can't use cascade in all scenarios, so in at least some cases you'll have to use a trigger anyway. Not a big fan of exceptionalism / inconsistency especially if the only reason is "I heard triggers are bad."

Comment: @AaronBertrand, you can replaced it with a trigger.

Comment: @jarlh so I should put three tires on my car, and a garbage can lid on the fourth wheel, knowing that if that garbage can lid should break down, I can add a fourth wheel in its place? Why not just use 4 wheels in the first place? You're not going to convince me that I should use CASCADE in a few places and triggers everywhere I can't. There's just no comprehensible logic in that.

Comment: @jarlh Thanks for dbfiddle. Sqlite behaviour is unexpected as it leaves employee with non-existing manager.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I'm sorry, but I can't understand why you say an on delete cascade fk is so different from a trigger - maybe because I've never used SQL Server. At least in theory a trigger and an on delete cascade fk can do exactly the same thing - delete child row(s).

Comment: @jarlh aside from syntax, that the actual code that implements cascade behavior is hidden and fixed, and that cascade has limitations that don't apply to triggers? How else do you want them to be different?

Comment: @jarlh And, to be frank, if you're not familiar with how they're different in SQL Server, maybe you shouldn't continue insisting they are interchangeable.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, for a while I forgot about the <sql server> tag, so I had more of a general, dbms agnostic approach. But after this I'll stay away of them if I ever do a SQL Server work. (I rarely use them anyway, but I don't mind using them. For example my car has 4 wheels, and if a rim is removed, its tire will also be gone.)